# How do I structure my react application if I will be using to build an informative website?

Tags: reactjs

How to structure a react application?

I just want to ask the best approach or way to create an informative site using react?

Do I do everything inside the APP.JS or should I do something in the index.html

Maybe I'm confused but I don't know how to structure my homepage in react.

Do you know or have a sample template that I can check and use as a reference?

Thanks in advance good people. :)

Comment: You will find many examples [here](https://reactjs.org/community/examples.html)

Comment: Got it! Thanks Man! :)